# Как сжаты изображения на https://direct.yandex.ru/

Tags: оптимизация, изображения, обработка-изображений

На сайте https://direct.yandex.ru/ при первом заходе, или медленном интернете видно что, изображение грузиться сначала серое, затем постепенно начинает становиться цветным. https://direct.yandex.ru/data3/desktop.blocks/b-morda-hero/__image/b-morda-hero__image_type_1.jpg  Вот отдельно картинка, как они сделали что картинка изначально серая, затем постепенно становится цветной?

Comment: Скорее всего просто прогрессивный jpeg, а чёрно-белость добавляет уже сам браузер

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51933